# convenience scripts for switching catkin workspaces

Tags: ros, catkin, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A while back I came across a post or mail of someone using some short bash script to conveniently source different setup.bash files. It was something along the lines of searching the home directory (up to a specified depth) for setup.bash files and then providing completion to switch to one of those workspaces.

I seem to be unable to find it again. I guess reimplementing it would not be too hard, but maybe something like this lying around in their .bashrc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134506/convenience-scripts-for-switching-catkin-workspaces/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it should be able to be modified easily to suit your needs: https://github.com/dornhege/ros_scripts

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-28**:
Yeah it wasn't, but this is very useful, thanks!